# Teamcity - Build Number - Pass into JS script

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, continuous-integration

This is my first time using TeamCity, so I'm still grasping all the concepts. I want to pass the build number from Teamcity into JS (node/gulp) script as a parameter. Does anyone have any thoughts on this. From my understanding the [predefined properties](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-buildNumber) are available at run time. In this case I'm assuming the following:

**Update:** added snippet used to modify the build number, but the environment variable doesn't seem to be coming through node.js

```
var setBuildNumber = function() {
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs'),
    buildNumber = 2.1;

if( typeof build !== 'undefined' ){ buildNumber = build.number; }

fs.readFile('public/index.html', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    var result = data.replace(/build number: 1.0/g, 'Build Number: ' +  buildNumber);
    
    if(err){ return console.log('file read error' + err); }

    fs.writeFile('public/index.html', result, 'utf8', function(err){
        if(err){ console.log('problem writing the file ' + err); }
    });
});
};
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

thanks,

Comment: The build number is accessible as an environment variable in build scripts. So you need to write a build script which writes the number to a file so that your code can consume it later. Exactly what the build script looks like is going to depend on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things

1. Change your js to read the build number from a properties file
2. Change your teamcity build to write/bake in the build number into the above properties file